# how to authorize parity trusted signer in Chrome app

Tags: wallets

How can I authorize a trusted signer in Google Chrome Parity app?
I keep getting this message:

> Authorization token is invalid

Comment: is it first time or did the message occurs for every token you provide?

Comment: it occurs every time in a new command promp

Answer (score 2):

after running Parity , generate the authorization token :
`parity signer new-token` and paste the token in the parity chrome input.

Comment: thanks, but where do I generate this token? Is it in the command promp?

Comment: When I enter the $  in the command promp it says " $ is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: run the cmd and type just : parity signer new-token without $